# Where put log4j properies file?

Tags: java, maven, logging, jboss

I added in `.pom` file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Generally it works. But where should I put `log4j.properites` file? I tried put it everywhere. In `WEB-INF`,  `resources` folder. I put this file in each folder in my app. And manually to `class` dir in `.war` file.

Didn't work.

Also I tried modify Jboss logging properies file. But it's not logging my log, only Jboss logs.

How can I change logging pattern and output file?

In pom file I also have

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

`src/main/resources/log4j.properties`

```
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%m\n

log4j.category.com.devdaily.log4jdemo.Log4JDemo=INFO, STDOUT
```

In java code

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
log.error("aaaaaaaa");
```

Console output

```
11:28:50,247 ERROR [Test] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) aaaaaaaa
```

---

Where I make mistake in my .properties file I get error on console. My `.properies` file. Maybe it's mistake inside?

```
log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.fileName=/home/mateusz/log4j/ussd.log
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=<%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}><%-5p><%C><%t><%x><%m>%n
```

Comment: The file belongs in /src/main/resources/log4j.properties. What are you trying to log? Define `Logger log = Logger.getLogger(); log.warn("it works");` in your code and see if it get formated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added dependency to my `pom.xml` with log4j, but configuration file is in in `jboss7dir/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` It's logging my app (I,m using log4j normally) and some jboss log.

Answer (score -1):

you can put log4.properties in the project's root folder.

Comment: Now I can manually load .properties file, but it sitll does not happen automatically